# Using NLog for Blazor Server Side

Tags: blazor-server-side, nlog

I am trying to use NLog on my project and following these [steps](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5)
I wonder how I could define the NLog lines in my Program.cs because there are no Main() and CreateHostBuilder() for Blazor server side.

Hope anyone can point me to right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it! It is

```
builder.Host.UseNLog();
```

**Edited to add more samples:**

```cs
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Logging.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions {
        CaptureMessageTemplates = true,
        CaptureMessageProperties = true
    });
builder.Host.UseNLog();
```